# what is showErros function do in jquery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am using Jquery [validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) to validate my form at client side. I need to know what [showError](http://docs.jquery.com/index.php?title=Plugins/Validation/Validator/showErrors&redirect=no) function does. It takes two parameters errorMap and errorList, what are these parameters.

Comment: `It takes two parameters errorMap and errorList, what are these parameters.` - I wonder where did you get that.

Answer (score 0):

Just to show error message. e.g:

```
<!doctype HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script> 
            <style type="text/css">
                * { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 96%; } label { width: 10em; float: left; } label.error { float: none; color: red; padding-left: .5em; vertical-align: top; } p { clear: both; } .submit { margin-left: 12em; } em { font-weight: bold; padding-right: 1em; vertical-align: top; } 
            </style>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                  $("#commentForm").validate();
                });
            </script> 
        </head>
        <body>
            <form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>A simple comment form with submit validation and default messages</legend>
                    <p>
                        <label for="cname">Name</label>
                        <em>*</em>
                        <input id="cname" name="name" size="25" class="required" minlength="2" onclick="$('#commentForm').validate().showErrors({'name': 'I know that your firstname is Pete, Pete!'});"/>
                    </p>
                    <p><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/></p>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```